# can't see country flags on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using International Telephone Input js for detecting country from dropdown and on the left hand side it shows country flag when you click on it shows whole dropdown, but on moile can't see flag images everything is ok, css background-position also is ok but don't see.

Here is a link for demo http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html and this is my code:

```
jQuery("#home_number").intlTelInput({
        allowExtensions: true,
        //autoFormat: false,
        //autoHideDialCode: false, 
        //autoPlaceholder: false,
        defaultCountry: "auto",
        setNumber : "Telephone number",
         geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
          $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
             callback(countryCode);
           });
         },
        nationalMode: false,
        numberType: "MOBILE",
        //onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
        //preferredCountries: ['cn', 'jp'],
        utilsScript: "/js/utils.js"
      });
```

Comment: Plese.. What mobile? What OS?  What Broser? All?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input#getting-started did you "override the path to flags.png in your CSS"?

Comment: only can't see on IOS and on all browsers(chrome,safari,etc..) @jasilva

Comment: yes with image all is ok, only on IPHONE, IPAD can't see flags and dropdown also doesn't open @AlejandroC